# use a linear mixed model to generate data in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, panel-data

I am new to longitudinal data. I need to simulate the following linear mixed model: there are 500 subjects and 10 visits. Let $Y_j$ be the response of the visit $j = 1, \ldots, 10$, and let $x_{j1}, x_{j2}$ be covariates. The responses have the following expected value:
$$E(Y_j) = \beta_0 + a_j + \beta_1 x_{j1} + \beta_2 x_{j1} x_{j2},$$
where $a_j$ is a random effect. I need to simulate this in R with a multivariate normal distribution with the following line of code:

```
Y_j <- rnorm(500, b0 + aj + b1*xj1 + b2*xj1*xj2, std)
```

The standard deviation does not really matter. So I need to use a linear mixed model to generate the data responses $Y_j$ for another linear mixed model that I need to study with `lmer`. I have the data of the covariates $x_{j1}, x_{j3}$ but I don't really know how to simulate the model for the mean of the response $E(Y_j)$. I have been researching but I did not find much.

Comment: This notation isn't working for you, because the left hand side by definition is a *number* indexed by $j,$ whereas on the right hand side there is a *random* quantity $a$ without an index.  The result is ambiguous.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes sorry, I added the index to the random component. It should be a random vector of size 500. But what I don't really understand is how to get a linear model for the expected value of Y. Should I just fit it as in linear regression?